# How to generate treat variable from difference between two observations?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
PERIOD <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
STATUS <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1)
TREAT <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
EXAMPLE <- data.frame(ID, PERIOD, STATUS, TREAT)
```

Now I want the TREAT variable to take the value 1 for all PERIOD = 2 where within the ID, STATUS = 1 in PERIOD = 1 and STATUS = 0 in PERIOD = 2.

In this example data, this would only be the case in the second row.

I presume this is going to use group_by(ID, PERIOD) and if_else() somehow, but I cannot figure out how to refer back to the value in a previous observation. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: What is `POVERTY`

Comment: The status in the original data is whether someone is below a certain poverty line. Had that name first in the example, but changed it for purposes of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [case_when()](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_6012/slides/chapter4.pdf). It is super useful and easy to use once you get into it. I did not really understand the conditions you wanted but here is an example you can use to get what you want.

```
  EXAMPLE %>% 
  mutate(TREAT = case_when(
    STATUS == 1 & PERIOD == 2 ~ 1,
    STATUS == 0 & PERIOD == 1 ~ 2,
    STATUS == 0 & PERIOD == 2 ~ 3,
    STATUS == 1 & PERIOD == 1 ~ 4,
    T ~ 99 # This is for all cases that are not covered by your conditions
  ))
```

Edit: Based on your comment i have edited my answer using `first()`and `last()`from dplyr. Is this what you need?

```
EXAMPLE %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(TREAT = case_when(
    first(STATUS) == 1 & last(STATUS) == 0 ~ 1,
    T ~ 0))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! This looks really helpful - not quite sure how to use it in my case though. 

For the coding of TREAT I need to consider values from both periods. So it should be 1 if there was a change from STATUS 1 to STATUS 0 between PERIOD 1 and and PERIOD 2.